# Creating fantasy crystal-like object to composite in a photoshoot

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, glass

first post here. I'm a beginner with Blender so I'm trying to get some advice on how to make the material part of a diamon/crystal type thing I'll add in a photoshoot.

I already asked this somewhere else so I'll post the screenshots with some reference images and more details about it.

I tried looking for tutorials online but none of them actually helped that much, so if anyone knows some tricks or a good tutorial let me know!

(The last two pics are the material nodes I used respectively for the top and bottom crystal)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6q-vCT-ZuV8

Or this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxY4uq8kH0Q

tutorial will help??